# Identifier based on conditions-R

Tags: r

I have a database , I am trying to find a identifier with following conditions
By taking first 3 letters from first, last 3 letters from last and last 4 digits of Phone1 if Phone1have empty cell we need to take last 4 digits of Phone2

```
df <- data.frame(first = c("apple", "grape", "rose", "Jasmine", "Apricots", "mango", "banana", "Blueberries"),
                 Last =  c("Jackfruit", "Kiwi", "Mulberry", "rabbit ", "pine", "Limes", "", "Nectarine"),
                 Phone1 = c("1234567890", "(456)7089123", "1230789456", "", "999999", " ", "1112223334", "9998887775"),
                 Phone2 = c("1234737650", "", "15", "8888888888", "99", "3336783245 ", "", "2222222222"))
```

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% mutate(ID = case_when(Phone2 %in% c('',' ') ~ paste0(substr(first,1,3), substr(Last,1,3),substr(Phone1, nchar(Phone1)-3, nchar(Phone1))),
+         Phone1 %in% c('',' ') ~ paste0(substr(first,1,3), substr(Last,1,3),substr(Phone2, nchar(Phone2)-3, nchar(Phone2))),
+         TRUE ~ paste0(substr(first,1,3), substr(Last,1,3),substr(Phone1, nchar(Phone1)-3, nchar(Phone1)))))
        first      Last       Phone1     Phone2         ID
1       apple Jackfruit   1234567890 1234737650 appJac7890
2       grape      Kiwi (456)7089123            graKiw9123
3        rose  Mulberry   1230789456         15 rosMul9456
4     Jasmine   rabbit               8888888888 Jasrab8888
5    Apricots      pine       999999         99 Aprpin9999
6       mango     Limes              3336783245 manLim3245
7      banana             1112223334               ban3334
8 Blueberries Nectarine   9998887775 2222222222 BluNec7775
>
```

Comment: If any phone number columns is less than 10 digits i Need to exclude is there any way to do so @Karthik S

Comment: you should add the packages you are using, also the extra whitespace on the number in row 6 is messing up your output

Comment: @priya, yes you can use something like "filter(nchar(Phone1) == 10)", but it's better if you can clean up data before this step. Like assigning specific pattern numbers etc.

Comment: @KarthikS when I tried this it is reading as NA with my first and last name instead of reading phone 2, for example manLimeNA instead of manLime3245

Comment: Can you share exact data that you are using? Coz I am able to see the same output as above.